# Click event is not working for button

Tags: jquery, onclick

I am having problems with my button `btndel` not working when I click.

Here's the script:

```
$('#btnadd').bind('click', function() {
    var scount = $("#support-list").find('li').length;
    var tmpStr = $('#txtaddsupportname').val();
    var str = “<li>";
    var str += “<img src='../wp-content/plugins/hamaJob/admin/assets/image/arrow.png'  width='16' height='16' class='handle'/>";

    str += "<strong alt="+ scount +">" + tmpStr + "</strong>";
    str += "<input type='button' id='btndel'/>";
    str += "</li>";

    $('#support-list').append(str);
});

$('#btndel').bind('click', function(){
      alert(this);
});
```

However, this script does work:

```
str += "<input type='button' id='btndel' onclick='btndel(this)'/>";
btndel = function(e){ alert(this); }
```

Could someone explain the difference?

Comment: are you adding the button dynamicaly? // check the double quotes in fourth line

Comment: you need to bind to the click event on the button which is available after it's created. another point, del button would be added multiple times. "id" cannot be duplicated. So, don't rely on the id in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newly added delete button is not in DOM, thats the reason why first example is not working. Use [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Check this updated code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LJ7sz/5/)

```
$('#btnadd').bind('click', function() {
    var scount = $("#support-list").find('li').length;
    var tmpStr = $('#txtaddsupportname').val();
    var str = "<li>";
     str += "<img src='../wp-content/plugins/hamaJob/admin/assets/image/arrow.png'  width='16' height='16' class='handle'/>";

    str += "<strong alt="+ scount +">" + tmpStr + "</strong>";
    str += "<input type='button' id='btndel'/>";
    str += "</li>";

   $('#support-list').append(str);
});
$( "#support-list" ).delegate( "#btndel", "click", function(){  
      alert(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you're binding your click event. The first example, you create the element `btndel` when a user clicks the button `btnadd`. So, when this function is called

```
$('#btndel').bind('click', function(){
  alert(this);
});
```

the element is not in the DOM for jQuery to bind the handler to the element.

The second example works because you create the element which references a function.

If you update the first to use either `event delegation` or to call `bind` after you create your element, it will work.

Here's a fiddle demonstrating both: http://jsfiddle.net/Z4ajL/

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>***[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9eg2C/)***</kbd>
*jQuery*

```
$(document).on('click','#btndel', function(){
      alert(this);
});
```